# Total order of given set

Tags: order-theory

For a given set $A$, if cardinality of $A$ is equal to zero or $1$, can we conclude that $\left \langle \mathcal{P}(A),\subseteq \right \rangle$ is a total ordering? I think when cardinality is one, then empty set and set $A$ will be comparable, but what about an empty set?

Comment: It’s true in both cases. When $A$ is empty, $\wp(A)$ has just one element, and a partial order with only one element is vacuously a total order.

Comment: What you mean by vacuously? I think for cardinality one, it is obvious since an empty set and $A$ will be comparable and it will yield a total order.

Comment: Loosely speaking, it means that there’s really nothing to check. The only way for a partial order to **fail** to be total is for it to have two elements that are not comparable, so if a partial order doesn’t even *have* two elements, it must be total.

Answer (score 1):

Well, for the case $A = \varnothing$, then $\mathcal P(A) = \{\varnothing\}$.

Take $S,T \in \mathcal P(A)$. Since $|\mathcal {P}(A)| = 1$ necessarily, it follows that $S = T = \varnothing$. (The sets need not be distinct.) The empty set is a subset of every set, so you will have both $S \subseteq T$ and $T \subseteq S$ (as $\varnothing \subseteq \varnothing$).

Thus, you have comparability (or connexity, as it is sometimes called).